# Is it considered rude to use commits as comments in VCS's

Tags: git, comments, commit, version-control

For example in `git` you could do

```
git commit --allow-empty -m"I like what this guy did"
```

I was considering using commits as a commenting system,
and I just wanted to see how that would go over.

Comment: Upvoted for being a neat idea. :·)

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to comment on a specific commit, [git-notes](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) allows you to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

You already heard that this is a bad idea, but this wasn't rationalized. The fact that SCM is not ment to be a forum, doesn't mean it shouldn't be one.

The reason this is a bad idea is that SCM is often being used to search the history for important/problematic commits. Adding unrelated noise to the SCM will make this job harder.

You wouldn't want to search for a commit message you vaguely recall the phrases "like this one" appears in it, and find plethora of messages of the form.

```
I like this one.
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh, SCMs are not considered appropriate for this usage. You may find yourself without commit rights rather quickly if you try this.